# Javascript loop through transaction lines and total them

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Using the below JSON as an example, how would I loop through the transaction lines and add them up?

As you can see there are two stores. In real life each store will have multiple transactions. But to get the total for the transaction I need to add up the lineValue in the transaction lines.

```
[{
    "transaction": 1,
    "store": 1,
    "transactionLines": [{
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 3,
            "lineValue": 25
        },

        {
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 2,
            "lineValue": 50
        },
        {
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 1,
            "lineValue": 100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "transaction": 2,
    "store": 2,
    "transactionLines": [{
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 2,
            "lineValue": 50
        },
        {
            "transactionId": 1,
            "lineId": 1,
            "lineValue": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Any help would be great. Below is as far as I've got and I'm stumped

```js
const inputData= "[{\r\n\t\t\"transaction\": 1,\r\n\t\t\"store\": 1,\r\n\t\t\"transactionLines\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 3,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 25\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 50\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 100\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t]\r\n\t},\r\n\t{\r\n\t\t\"transaction\": 2,\r\n\t\t\"store\": 2,\r\n\t\t\"transactionLines\": [{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 2,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 50\r\n\t\t\t},\r\n\t\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"transactionId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineId\": 1,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"lineValue\": 100\r\n\t\t\t}\r\n\t\t]\r\n\t}\r\n]"

const input = JSON.parse(inputData);
//console.log(input);

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i ++) 
{
console.log(input.transaction)

}
```

As you can see, I'm rather new to looping through the array let alone different levels of the array. My assumption from the above snippet is that it should print the transaction IDs to the console... clearly this isn't my end goal but I haven't managed to get that right so far.

Any pointers or direction to learning relevant learning resource would be great thank you.

Many thanks everyone.

Comment: Hi, did input.transaction work or you meant input[i].transactions as input is an array. In that case, for the sum you just need to replay console.log(input.transaction) to some sum=sum+input[i].transactions and return the value of sum outside the loop. There are definitely ways to use reduce as well to do it. refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

Brother I am not so much pro in JS but I think this code will work for you

```
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
// console.log(data[i].transactionLines) //looping through transactionLines
    for(let j=0;j<data[i].transactionLines.length;j++){
        console.log(data[i]["transactionLines"][j]["transactionId"]) //looping through transactionID
    }
}
```